# Concatenating buffers in JavaScript vs Elixir

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

I am currently attempting to recreate an Elixir function that I use for encrypting data in JavaScript:

```
def encrypt(data, key) do
  iv = "0123456789ABCDEF"
  data = :crypto.crypto_one_time(:aes_256_cbc, key, iv, data, encrypt: true, padding: :pkcs_padding)
  Base.encode64(data)
end
```

```js
function encrypt(data, key) {
  const iv = "0123456789ABCDEF"
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv)
  const encryptedData = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64')
  return encryptedData
}
```

Using both this functions, I can successfully encrypt `data` using the key `0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF` to `eLh5vbl3paGUGVIio2iEIw==`. However, since the IV should never be hardcoded, the common practice is to prepend it before base-64 encoding the result. I can easily do this in Elixir, as shown below:

```
def encrypt(data, key) do
  iv = :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(16)
  data = :crypto.crypto_one_time(:aes_256_cbc, key, iv, data, encrypt: true, padding: :pkcs_padding)
  Base.encode64(iv <> data)
end
```

I can't get working in JavaScript though:

```js
function encrypt(data, key) {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv)
  const encryptedData = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64')
  return Buffer.from(iv + Buffer.from(encryptedData, 'base64')).toString('base64')
}
```

The problem is not working with the cipher, but getting the buffers compatible with each other. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working:

```
def encrypt(data, key) do
  iv = :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(16)
  data = :crypto.crypto_one_time(:aes_256_cbc, key, iv, data, encrypt: true, padding: :pkcs_padding)
  Base.encode64(iv <> data)
end

def decrypt(data, key) do
  <<iv::binary-16, data::binary>> = Base.decode64!(data)
  :crypto.crypto_one_time(:aes_256_cbc, key, iv, data, encrypt: false, padding: :pkcs_padding)
end
```

```js
function encrypt(data, key) {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv)
  const encryptedData = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex')
  return Buffer.concat([iv, Buffer.from(encryptedData, 'hex')]).toString('base64')
}

function decrypt(data, key) {
  const iv = Buffer.from(data, 'base64').subarray(0, 16)
  const encryptedData = Buffer.from(data, 'base64').subarray(16)
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv)
  return decipher.update(encryptedData) + decipher.final()
}
```